# Can't send file over udp between two computers

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I am trying to send a file once and have it received by multiple clients. I thought udp would be good for this. Ive written the following code and if the server and the client are ran on the same computer I can send and receive the file. If I ran them in different computers connected to the same network I get nothing. I can send data through tcp with the same computers. What can I do to either use udp correctly or send a file to multiple clients at the same time?

**code for sender**

```
import socket
import time

SERVERADDR = (socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 1234)
print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
buffer = 2048
udpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

def sendFile(filepath):
    f=open(filepath,"rb")
    data = f.read(buffer)
    while (data):
        if(udpServer.sendto(data,SERVERADDR)):
            data = f.read(buffer)
            time.sleep(0.0001)
    f.close()


temp = input("press a button to send")
sendFile("send.jpg")
```

**code for receiver**

```
import socket

buffer = 2048
SERVERIP = input("enter ip\n")
SERVERADDR = (SERVERIP, 1234)
udpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udpServer.bind(SERVERADDR)

def receiveFile():
    try:
        udpServer.settimeout(3)
        data = udpServer.recvfrom(buffer)[0]
        f = open("received.jpg",'wb')
        try:
            while(data):
                f.write(data)
                udpServer.settimeout(0.2)
                data = udpServer.recvfrom(buffer)[0]
        except socket.timeout:
            f.close()
            udpServer.close()
            print ("file downloaded")
    except socket.timeout:
        udpServer.close()
        print ("no file to download")

receiveFile()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're using the functions' return values as the documentation suggests you should. For example, *`sendto()` ... Return(s) the number of bytes sent...*.

Comment: Bind your sockets to 0.0.0.0, or `''`, not a specific IP address. Then they can receive from anywhere. But this code will never work without detection and remedying of lost or duplicate or out-of-order datagrams.

Comment: You can send to multiple computers at the same time either by sending to a multicast address (and having all receivers join that multicast group to receive) or by sending each packet via unicast to each of the receiving computers in turn.  Either way, user207421's comment is worth repeating -- UDP *will* drop/duplicate/re-order packets on you, so your protocol will result in corrupted files most of the time unless you come up with a way to detect and recover from those events.  (and coming up with a protocol that handles them gracefully is non-trivial)

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk since the `sendto()` function returns the number of bytes sent I should be able to send all data and stop if none are sent by something even like this:
`while (udpServer.sendto(data,SERVERADDR)):`
`data = f.read(imageBuffer)`

Comment: @user207421 using '' works if I am sending both of the files are on the same windows machine. On separate machines I dont get any data. At this point I am wondering if I have problems with my modem firewall or windows firewall. The small time spent waiting is to remedy out of order datagrams but I might try a more complex way to order the bytes if I can get to send anything across computers.

Comment: @HMertAcr So fix the binds, as I already told you. The reliability objections remain. The fact that it works within the localhost proves exactly nothing about transmission over a network. And I don't know what you mean by 'the small time spent waiting', or how that could possibly 'remedy out of order datagrams' even if it existed here, which it doesn't. There is no time spent waiting here other than blocking inside `recvfrom()`. `settimeout()` is not a wait.

Comment: @user207421 What I meant by small time spent waiting was `time.sleep(0.001)` in the sender so that the receiver doesnt receive the bytes out of order. Not a permanent or good solution I know. I fixed the binds thank you.